# Software for automated database processing

Tags: dataset, data, bigdata, software-recommendation, data-table

I faced a problem which I'd like to solve w/o any programming. And looking for a software to do this.

I have a dataset, for example: (brand-id, brand-name, product-class-name;)

```
0, Audi, economy business premium;
1, Rolls Royce, luxury;
2, Seat, economy;
3, Tesla, business premium;
```

And I'd like to automatically process this dataset, resulting in creating an additional table to classify parameters in column 3, like: (product-class-id, product-class-name, brand-id;)

```
0, economy, 0 2;
1, business, 0 3;
2, premium, 0 3;
3, luxury, 1;
```

Is there any database managing tool with features like this one? (preferably Mac)

Comment: You can use Google DataFlow, it enables you to do such operations on datasets without programming anything. The framework has lots of tools to use. Not free, of course.

Comment: You should be able to use Power Query in Excel for this, however I would not consider that a database management tool.

Answer (score 1):

Do you consider SQL to be programming? Because at the very least you're going to need to do some SQL manipulations to solve this. There's no visual tool that I know of that will do this for you (*especially* for OSX!)

I don't know why you have a barrier for a new language; if you were willing to do this in python it could be solved relatively quickly.

Comment: No doubt, that's just a few mins with the proper approach. But I need this task to be done by non-developers. We have a bunch of this kind manipulations to be done continuously.  I'm rather sure that there is a GUI(or excel-difficulty) tool for it. Not found yet)

Comment: @FedorAlexandrovich if that’s the case then this is a GUI issue, not a data science issue. You probably need help from someone that is a Mechanical Turk specialist or something like that. A custom interface is what you need - not a data scientist.